# Remove code redundancy for an array of checkbox

Tags: asp.net

I have a series of checkboxes in an ASP.Net page. Every checkbox makes call to single function that accepts the checkbox id as a parameter.

The problem is that the code is now redundant. Is there a way to generalize the code. Attaching the sample code below:

```
        protected void chkAddlDetails_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkAddlDetails.Checked == true)
            {
                blnShouldLock("chkAddlDetails");
                Panel9.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Panel9.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        protected void chkDeValidate_CheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkDeValidate.Checked == true)
            {
                blnShouldLock("chkDeValidate");
                Panel10.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Panel10.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        ............
        ............ and similar code repeats for other check boxes
```

As the checkbox count is increasing the code is expanding and getting more redundant.

Can anyone assist to have a generalized code to avoid redundancy. Appreciate if a pseudo code can be provided.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same event for all your checkboxes. You can then cast `sender` to the `CheckBox` that fired the event.

If each panel corresponds to a single checkbox, you can name the panels with the names of the checkboxes and suffix them with "Panel". For example a checkbox called `chkDevalidate` could have a panel called `chkDevalidatePanel` and the below method should work for all your checkboxes. If the same panel is shown or hidden by multiple checkboxes you'll need to map them between each other using a `Dictionary` or similar.

```
protected void GenericCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
    Panel panel = (Panel)Page.FindControl(checkbox.ID + "Panel");

    if (checkbox.Checked)
    {
        blnShouldLock(checkbox.ID);
        panel.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        panel.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Greg - I have prepared the function to provide generic handling. However, this function is not being invoked when I click on the check box. Any idea why this may be happening.

Comment: How do you know it's not being invoked, have you added a breakpoint? If so, have you ensured it's set as the checkbox's `OnCheckedChanged` event?

Comment: Can you please let me know how can I invoke this function.

Comment: It's probably a separate issue that's unrelated, so you need to accept my answer to this question and make a new one with full code examples so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

or without an if.

```
panel.Visible = checkbox.Checked
```